# How to allow user to download file from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem in asp.net. Actually I am letting my website's visitor to install an window application from that web site. I have added my application without creating installer so it is just an .exe file which is showing a normal form. But the problem is when user tries to download that file an error message is being shown that says that "This file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep this file anyway?" So I don't want to display that message. can you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could embed your .exe file in a zip-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither a "problem" of ASP.NET nor the WinForms application. This is a thing that modern browsers do when you download an application or document that might contain (potentially malicious) executable parts. If there was a "this thing won't harm anybody"-flag for downloads, do you think that this would only be set by "nice" developers?

Comment: Dear Thorsten actually my code doesn't contain any thing which might harm anybody's computer. Actually it contains a winform. When a user open that Form a batch file will store in start up folder. Do you have any idea how to store that batch file start up folder directly from ASP.NET application without using winform.

Comment: You actually have to understand that an ASP.NET "application" runs solely server side. There is no way that you can do anything on the client machine from your code-behind. Also, it runs in a browser, so even *if* you could do anything like that through JavaScript, for example, you'd be out of luck if the browser sandboxes your code. For the browser it doesn't matter what your code does. It has no code inspection. All it does is recognize that a file was downloaded from the internet and marks it as potentially dangerous. Windows then shows the message you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ActiveX to download file from internet explorer browser. This might help. The way to make download in given below.

Example:

```
 public class Downloader
    {
      public void DownloadFile()
      {
         using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
         {
             webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.stackoverflow.com/stacks.txt", @"c:\stacks.txt");
         }
      }
    }
```